# Ionic - parse millisecond(long) date to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, date-parsing

I am new to ionic, typescript and angularjs. In regular **java** parsing long date is easy

```
    Date date = new Date(1915654554);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

But in Ionic-**TypeScript**, i tried like this

```
    let date=new Date(1915654554);  
    alert(date);   //shows invalid date
```

Actually i am getting  `"PublishingDate": "/Date(1497426961890)/"` from web-api

**HTML** code :

```
       <p>
         {{ getActualDate(notice.PublishingDate) }}
      </p>
```

**TypeScript** code:

```
       getActualDate(lDate)
      {
           var d=lDate.substring(6,19);
           let date=new Date(d)
          return date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date. getFullYear();

                  //shows Nan/Nan/Nan
      }
```

its showing invalid date. any help, suggestions please. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean shows invalid date?

Comment: And is there a specific format you want it in?

Comment: yes, dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: Awesome just answered. Hopefully that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your Java code is outmoded. The *java.time* classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Specifically, `Instant` instead of `Date`: `Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_915_654_554L )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You can use the [Javascript Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp).

```
let date=new Date(1915654554);  
alert(date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date. getFullYear()); // 22/1/1970
```

The more important thing to remember is `getMonth` returns a number between 0-11, so you have to add 1 to it if you want it to be 1-12.

Comment: @faceturn I disagree with that duplicate question. Although similar the date format is different. The accepted answer on the duplicate question is a much longer format than OP asked about which was dd/MM/yyyy format. Also my answer was posted before the duplicate question was marked. I was not aware of that question already being asked. Although the two questions are different because of that format.

Comment: @CharlieFish i edited my question, its showing Nan/Nan/Nan like

Comment: @Onkar You need a parseInt, for example `let date=new Date(parseInt(d))`, you also have a typo when declaring `d`. You need to create the date from a number not a string.